# Unable to safely remove usb-drive

Tags: usb-drive, unmount

I am unable to safely remove my Nokia E63 (connected via cable).

```
Error detaching: helper exited with exit code 1: Detaching device /dev/sdc
USB device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2)
SYNCHRONIZE CACHE: FAILED: No such file or directory
(Continuing despite SYNCHRONIZE CACHE failure.)
STOP UNIT: FAILED: No such file or directory
```

What does this mean??

This happens with every USB storage device I connect and exchange data with. Removing it directly results in the data being written incompletely.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug and it [has been filled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/466575).

The workaround is to go to terminal and execute `sudo umount /dev/sdx`, where *sdx* is where your drive is mounted. If you don't know, open an app which will show you where your drive is mounted - GParted or Disk Utility for example.

Ussualy it would be *sdc* if you have two hard disks, or *sdb* if you have only one hard disk.

Comment: as I understood, `sudo umount /dev/sdx` is the same as select 'eject' option instead of 'safely remove'